# Copy shell configuration from one machine to another?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, sh

I've got login to another server where shell configurations are not like I would want. For example I don't see my username and CWD on prompt, and when I press arrow key, instead of giving last entered command, it gives me `^[[A`. So I wonder if can just move my profile configuration from my machine to that server?

I copied `.bashrc` and `.profile` files and tried to execute them, but it didn't do anything. What should I do? Do I need some other files? Or I can only create all configurations from scratch?

Comment: The first thing to check is if the shell on the other server is what you expect. You tagged `bash`. Are you sure the shell is Bash? How do you know? What happens when you run `exec bash -l`? Is it better? the same? some error?

Answer (score 0):

Actually such configuration could be in different scripts. But you should copy **.profile** **.bash_profile** and **.bashrc** and then logout and login.

Comment: In my machine there is only `.profile` and `.bashrc`. Also my machine output `bin/bash` with command `echo $SHELL`, and on that server `bin/sh`

Comment: bash and sh are different shells and .bashrc is for bash only. You could try passing the configuration from .bashrc to .profile and see what happens (some command may not work, of course). Or you could ask the server administrator to change your shell to bash.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard configuration like you mention is usually in **`~/.inputrc`**, which you should be able to copy to most *nix machines.